# Defining median for discrete distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, definition, median

In probability theory, a median of a probability distribution is a number $M$ such that the CDF of this distribution $F_\xi(x)$ satisfies

$F_\xi(M)=\frac{1}{2} \tag1$

This works for continuous distributions, but for discrete distributions median would almost always be undefined if we were using this definition. How is it defined in the discrete case? Does it have similarity with $(1)$?

To stress the difference from median of a **set** and illustrate my thoughts, the CDF looks [something like this](http://www.probabilitycourse.com/images/chapter3/CDF-Discrete_b.png).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How is it defined in the discrete case?

In the general case, a median is defined as any number $m$ such that $P(\xi\leqslant m)\geqslant\frac12$ and $P(\xi\geqslant m)\geqslant\frac12$, or, equivalently, such that $F_\xi(m^-)\leqslant\frac12\leqslant F_\xi(m)$.

Medians are not unique, in general.

*Exercise:* Determine the set of medians of the distribution such that $P(\xi=0)=P(\xi=1)=\frac12$.

Comment: So, for example, if my $F_\xi(x)=(0 \text{ if } x<0)\&(1 \text{ if } x\ge 0)$, then median is not defined?

Comment: There is always at least one median. In the case of your comment, there is exactly one median and I am sure you can compute it...

Comment: I obtained $M=0$ in my example and $M\in[0;1]$ in your exercise. But why is $(P(\xi\le M) \ge \frac{1}{2}) \implies (F_\xi (M^-) \le \frac{1}{2})$ true? Alternatively, how can I get the function $G_\xi (x)= P(\xi \ge x)$ if I know $F_\xi (x)$?

Comment: How you imagined that $P(\xi\leqslant M)\geqslant\frac12$  could imply $F_\xi(M^-)\leqslant\frac12$ is beyond me, I am afraid. What is the definition of $F_\xi$ to you?

Comment: My bad, I meant $P(\xi\ge M) \ge \frac{1}{2}$. Definition is $F_\xi (x)=P(\xi\le x)$.

Comment: ~~Did you mean $P(\xi \le M) \le \frac{1}{2}$? (and $P(\xi \ge M) \ge \frac{1}{2}$) By the definition you used it seems like all numbers greater than a median would also be a median.~~ Nope, nvm, got confused.

Comment: @Zephyr Somebody needs to check the definition of being a median, here... (Unrelated: FYI, the condition $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=P(X=2)=\frac12$ is impossible.)

Comment: @Did Hmm, in case odd no of 'x' values satisfy the condition, then the middle one is median if arranged in ascending order of 'x' values else take the average of middle 2 'x' values right ?

Comment: @Did Yes it's impossible. I don't know what I was thinking when writing that comment. Can you check if my previous comment is correct ?

Comment: Intriguing downvote... @Zephyr Is that you?

Answer (score 0):

The way I *remember* it being defined in this case was from either middle school or high school.  Say your distribution is

$$10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 65, 76, 89$$

There's no middle number to use as the median, so I'd use the average of the two middle numbers: $45$.

It gives me some comfort that my memory agrees with [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) on the subject.

Comment: This would be the median of a set, as I understand it.

Comment: This is a common rule for the *empirical* median (i.e. this is an estimate of the median, given a finite dataset).