# How many messages with exponentially distributed time can be sent with probability $\frac 1 2$ in at most $15$ minutes?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume that the time to send a message follows an exponential distribution with $\lambda = 8$ and is independent from the rest of the messages. The messages are sent sequentially, one after another. How many messages can be sent with probability $\frac 1 2$ in at most $15$ minutes?

**My attempt**: Let $X_i$ denote the time to send the $i$-th message. We know that $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \frac 1 8$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \frac{1}{64}$. Let $Y_n$ denote the time to send $n$ messages, i.e. $Y_n = \sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^{n} X_i$. It follows that $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = \frac n 8$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y_n) = \frac{n}{64}$ since the $X_i$'s are independent.

We now have:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left\{Y_n \leq 15\right\} = \mathbb{P}\left\{\frac{Y_n - \frac n 8}{\frac n 8} \leq \frac{15 - \frac n 8}{\frac n 8}\right\} = \mathbb{P}\left\{Y_n^* \le \frac{15 - \frac n 8}{\frac n 8}\right\} = \frac 1 2
$$
where $Y_n^* \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ by the central limit theorem. From here it immediately follows that:
$$
\frac{15 - \frac n 8}{\frac n 8} = 0 \Longrightarrow n = 120
$$

---

I first tried using Chebyshev's inequality, but had no idea how to proceed. Can anyone tell me if I did everything correctly?

Comment: Also note that $Y_n\sim Gamma(n,8)$ Thus $16Y_n\sim Gamma(\frac{2n}{2},\frac{1}{2})=\chi^2_{df=2n}$ This may give you more exact answer but you would have to use table of chi squared with different degrees of freedom or use excel to get closest value so that $P(16Y_i<16(15))=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Also remember if $P(Y^*_n< 0)=\frac{1}{2}$ not $P(Y^*_n< \frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Kamster: Thanks a lot, I realized the thing about $Y_n$ having a gamma distribution, but did not realize I could use it to my advantage. As for your other comment, I solved for $n$ as if it were $0$, but for some reason wrote $\frac 1 2$. Can you spot any other mistakes?

Comment: if you are okay with approximation which seems like not a bad idea since your $n$ is fairly large everything seems right

Comment: also if you dont want to use chi square table just use pgamma function in r or something similar to find probabilities with different $n$ choosing one has probability closest to 0.5

Comment: If you got a pretty small $n$ I would wary because then it would be very close to normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the times are independent and distributed exponentially with parameter $\lambda$ then the number in a time interval $t$ has a Poisson distribution with mean $t \lambda$ and variance $t \lambda$. In this case $t \lambda=120$, So the number of messages in 15 minutes $\sim \text{Poisson}(120)$. Now $120$ is large-ish so we may use the normal approximation $N(120,120)$, so the median number of messages $\approx$ the mean number of messages $=120$.

Which is what you have already found.

Comment: And the true answer is $119$ since $P(\text{Poisson}(120)\leqslant119)\approx49\%$ and $P(\text{Poisson}(120)\leqslant120)\approx52\%$.

Comment: @Did except for the ambiguity of the median of a discrete distribution. Under the interpretation in this  [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069158/defining-median-for-discrete-distribution) 120 is the median. It is also what the approximation for the median on the Poisson Wikipedia page gives, for what that is worth?

Comment: @Did We can probably justify any value for the median in $[119,120]$ if we put our minds to it.

Comment: The question does not mention the median. If one sticks to the formulation of the question, the answer is 119.

Comment: OK, I will conceded that